# Setting the default "from" address when replying to messages in shared folders/inboxes?

Tags: office365, outlook.com

If you're using a shared folder or inbox on Outlook.com (I'm talking exclusively about webmail here), it automatically sets your email address (ex. you@company.com) as the default in the "From" field whenever you reply to a message in that inbox. You can easily click on the "From" field to change this to the shared inbox's address (ex. shared@company.com), but you have to do this every single time you reply to a message. No matter how tech-savvy or vigilant you are, it is very easy to forget this.

Is there a way to configure the shared inbox to use shared@company.com as the default "From" address? This is doable in the Outlook desktop application, but I've not been able to find where this is done in Outlook's webmail.

Comment: just something to keep in mind: this might be dictated by how your Exchange administrator has configured your webmail; are you the administrator or user?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @mael. I'm a user, so I'll ask my admin to check. It seems odd it would be a configuration thing if it's possible in the desktop app, just not webmail, though.